# Extract string between repeating characters?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I can't seem to figure out the right way to use `FIND` `SEARCH` `MID` and `LEFT` when attempting this in excel.

Here is an example of a string:

```
""["{\".tag\": \"file\", \"path\": {\"namespace_relative\": {\"ns_id\": \"7967408752\", \"relative_path\": \"/Assets Creative/National/2021 Brand Winter/Web/Nana-FR-16x9_WEB15F.mp4\", \"is_shared_namespace\": true}}, \"display_name\": \"Tana-FR-16x9_WEB15F.mp4\", \"file_id\": \"id:rAWlCkcfulAAAAAAAAKx4g\"}"]""
```

Quotations included.

all within the same spreadsheet. What I'm trying to do is extract the text between:

`"relative_path\": \"` and `", \"is_shared_namespace\": true}},`

so that would be `Assets Creative/National/2021 Brand Winter/Web/Nana-FR-16x9_WEB15F.mp4` (without the `/` and `\` in the string)

I'll keep working on it in the mean time but all help is immensely appreciated.

***EDIT***
I think I got the answer:

`=MID(M4,FIND("/Ass",M4)+1,FIND("is_shared",M4)-FIND("/Ass",M4)-7)`

I'm not sure if this is the correct answer or the best answer but it is outputting what I need so far. My concern now is if the file doesn't end in mp4

Thanks,

Comment: If you know those are the only two ways the string starts, then use `=SUBSTITUTE()` formula to remove the front part. use `=FIND()` nested within '=LEFT` to remove the back part. If you use `=MID()` then you'll also need the '=LEN()` formula

Comment: thanks @gns100 the problem I'm having is I can't enter "" within the formula. I've updated the question to show that there is only one requirement rather than the two.

Comment: Yes I think you'll need to use concatenation and `=CHAR(34)` everywhere you see the double quote `"`

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few solutions for this. I have collected all of them in this artile, when I was considering the address string, separated by commas.

http://www.mkrgeo-blog.com/good-way-to-sanitizing-a-bulk-address-list-part-1-excel-vba/

I think, you could consider the FILTERXML function:

```
   =FILTERXML(“<t><s>”&SUBSTITUTE(F1,”, “,”</s><s>”)&”</s></t>”,”//s[position()=last()-1]”)
```

or MID function, as you said:

```
   =MID(A1, SEARCH(“,”,A1) + 1, SEARCH(“,”,A1,SEARCH(“,”,A1)+1) – SEARCH(“,”,A1)-1)
```

although the difference between MID and FILTERXML function is significant, as the MIN() function allowes us to extract the text just after the first character occurrence. By using FILTERXML() function, you can extract the string from any random place in your long string, as long as you are not lost in the order calculation. Every specific character occurrence, while space should be counted from the left to the right.

In the case, when you need two substrings from the middle of your main string, you can expand the formulas above:

```
       =TEXTJOIN(“, “,,FILTERXML(“<t><s>”&SUBSTITUTE(A1,”, “,”</s><s>”)&”</s></t>”,”//s[position()=2 or position() =3]”))
```

where adding TEXTJOIN() function, you will have everything in one cell (not spilled).

```
        =MID(A1, SEARCH(“,”,A1) + 1, SEARCH(“,”,A1,SEARCH(“,”,A1,SEARCH(“,”,A1)+1)+1) – SEARCH(“,”,A1)-1)
```

See more hints here:

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/06/01/split-text-string-excel/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65955114/vba-excel-if-condition-for-splitting-address-columns

Answer (score 0):

```
=MID(A1,FIND(String1,A1)+LEN(String1)+1,FIND(String2,A1)-(FIND(String1,A1)+LEN(String1)+1)-1)
```

or, if you want to hardcode the strings, you need to escape the double quote with a double quote:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("""relative_path\"": \""",A1)+LEN("""relative_path\"": \""")+1,FIND(""", \""is_shared_namespace\"": true}}",A1)-(FIND("""relative_path\"": \""",A1)+LEN("""relative_path\"": \""")+1)-1)
```

Comment: Ron - you should probably change your answer and add that he should define the strings if the first solution to be used, I did it in a similar way where I have the strings he is searching for in cell A1 and A2 and his list starts in A3 downwards and the formula is pasted into B2 and he just needs to drag down the B2 until he reaches the end of list in A column - `=RIGHT( LEFT( A3, FIND( $A$1, A3 ) - 2 ), LEN( LEFT( A3, FIND( $A$1, A3 ) - 2 ) ) - FIND( $B$1, LEFT( A3, FIND( $A$1, A3 ) ) ) - 20 )`